# Filtering JavaScript Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, filter

I have a Java script that looks something like this in the browser console

https://www.dropbox.com/s/53spm6lf7o6oa8z/Selecci%C3%B3n_2015-07-10-001.png

What I would like to do is return a filtered object based on the content of the property "class"... I have been looking into JQuery's .grep() or .filter() but they not quite work as this object is not an array, and I have not been able to converted into one....

I will appreciate pointer into the right direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// object
var obj = your_obj;
var matchedClass = "your_matched_class";
var filteredObj = {};
for (var key in obj) { // iterating over object and checking for class
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key) && obj[key].class === matchedClass) {
       filteredObj[key] = obj[key]; 

  }
}
```

Comment: great!! it works as expected, correct me if I'm wrong would be this faster or slower than doing with a native function like 'filter'???

Comment: In our scenario, we can use filter/grep but for that first we have to convert obj into array and then again array to object which i feel is not appropriate and will be slower. Let us say, we could use some native function, however, internally that would also have performed iteration and check property. I believe the above will not affect your performance

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a tool/framework to make this easy, it sounds like you're after [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs)

It supports _.filter, as well as other convenient functions which will probably help the processing you're after. If you can be more specific about your desired output, we can probably help you with a specific answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the object's keys with:

`var keys = Object.keys(myObj)`

and then filter the list of keys:

```
var matchingKeys = keys.filter(function(key) {
   return myObj[key].class === 'somevalue')`
}
```

and then grab those keys out of the object.

Comment: Your codes return an array with the keys thta meets the filtering criteria, what is the fastest way to get a copy of the original object with only those keys....